# How to make Selenium use localhost proxy

Tags: firefox, selenium, proxy

I have a perl based selenium script with the following statement :

```
$sel = Test::WWW::Selenium->new( host => "localhost", 
                            port => 4444, 
                            browser => "*chrome", 
                            browser_url => "https://$ARGV[0]/" );
```

This throws up the Firefox browser. I want that when the Firefox browser is thrown up it is configured to use my proxy namely 127.0.0.1:8080 where I have a proxy service already started. How can I accomplish this without making any changes to the above shown code?

Comment: You get Firefox when you ask Selenium for "*chrome"? Odd. Also note that "throw up" means "to puke". Use "starts" instead.

Answer (score 0):

For Firefox, you need to [create a profile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16423309/how-to-create-a-new-persistent-firefox-profile-with-selenium-in-python) for Selenium. Start Firefox with `-ProfileManager -no-remote` to be able to select this profile. Configure it accordingly.

When starting Firefox with the Selenium webdriver, you can then specify the profile to use with `webdriver.firefox.profile`

I couldn't find a solution to achieve the same with the Perl API. You might have to hack the sources to be able to specify the profile. Just add `-P` plus the name of the profile to the command line options of the browser process.

Alternatively, you can insert a script in the path variable before you run the tests. For example, on Unix:

```
#!/bin/bash

/usr/bin/firefox -P selenium
```

Save this in, say, `$HOME/selenium/bin/firefox`, make this new file executable and:

```
export PATH="$HOME/selenium/bin/firefox;$PATH"
```

The tests will not think that the script is the firefox executable and run that. The script will then run Firefox with the correct parameters.