# How to save Firefox Profile with Selenium and Python

Tags: python, selenium, firefox

I want to save a Firefox Profile after being used by Selenium since I need its data (cookies,sessions,history) to remain in that profile, so I can access it later. I know how to load profile, but I don't know how to save it after use.

I already searched for this and unable to find any solution. I also refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16423309/how-to-create-a-new-persistent-firefox-profile-with-selenium-in-python) answer, but I couldn't understand what should I do.